# xmlDatabinding configuration with cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, cxf

I'm trying to publish a service with Spring boot cxf starter using as Databinding xmlbean as follows:

```
@Bean
public Endpoint nameServiceEndpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new NameWsServiceImpl());
        endpoint.publish("/NamesWsService");
        endpoint.setDataBinding(new XmlBeansDataBinding());
     return endpoint;
}
```

when i try to run the app i got the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.createMininumEscapeHandler

in my pom i have as dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: if the solution is good please vote up

Comment: thx for your response , i already marked your response as resolved

Comment: Why are you mixing up different CXF versions? You should use the same version for all CXF dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use spring boot web services but you should include wsdl4j

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

the reference is https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

Answer (score 0):

Or you simply use the enterprise & production ready [cxf-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter), which deserves it's name - since you don't have to care about `wsdl4j` or `xmlbeans`. This thing does everything for you, just use it in a plain Spring Boot project. The following `pom.xml` has **everything** you need **ever** to do SOAP with Spring Boot & CXF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.codecentric.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-boot-simple</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cxf-boot-simple</name>
    <description>Demo project for using Spring Boot Starter CXF</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The companion Maven plugin [cxf-spring-boot-starter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter-maven-plugin) does the heavy lifting for you: just place your **wsdl** file somewhere inside `src/main/resources` and it will generate all needed Java class files from your WSDL, incl. the Service Endpoint Interface (SEI) implementation - which enables the cxf-spring-boot-starter to **automatically** fire up your SOAP services - 100% contract first! Just as you know all the other frameworks in the Spring Boot universe. Here's also a fully working example project: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-samples/tree/master/cxf-boot-simple

The only thing left for you, is to do the business transformation into or from your internal domain models :) Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It seems `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws` dependent on an old jar that missing `createMininumEscapeHandler`.
Try to fix it by import `cxf-bom`, it works for me!

```xml
<!-- import cxf-bom -->
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
       <artifactId>cxf-bom</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <!-- just cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```